# FirebaseAuth validation is not working after installing the app first time from play store

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase authentication for my project. Everything is fine, but when I first install the app from playstore my code is not working, it directly sends the user to main activity. But then if I logout from their it is working fine. And when I first install the app from android studio also then it is working fine, only after installing the app from play store this validation is not working. I am so confused what is wrong with my code, months ago it was working fine, but now it is not working. Can some please help me. In this case I can't even check the what is the value of 'user' here, as I can't use the debugging tools, because it is happening only after installing the app from play store. Please help if someone has any idea about this problem.

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();


        FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if (user != null) {
            sendUserToMainActivity();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What type of Auth is used here? signInWithEmailAndPassword?

Comment: Yes @majuran, signInWithEmailAndPassword

Comment: Where is this code located? in Which activity?

Comment: It is located in LoginActivity, from here I am sending the user to MainActivity, if the user is authenticated.

Comment: It means previous login credentials are still in your app. did you uninstall your android studio version of your app before installing play store version of your app?

Comment: Can you share your manifest file ?

Comment: Yes of course I did. @majuran

Comment: Can u please tell me what possibly could be wrong their, @A.J

Comment: Use Toast to debug your playstore version, "Toast.makeText(this, user. 
getUid(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();", And check that Uid with your firebase console

Comment: Make sure your login activity is the activity which opens first when the app is launched

Comment: Yes of course, LoginActivity is the launcher activity. @A.J

Comment: Yes thanks. I am gonna try, sometimes these little things doesn't come to mind. @majuran

Answer (score 0):

Use Toast to debug your play store version effectively

```
        if (user != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, user.getUid(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            sendUserToMainActivity();
        }
```

And check that Uid with your firebase console.

Comment: Yes, using this I just discovered the 'user' returns the last username which was logged in last time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if something changed in how (or more likely *when*) the current user is set. Can you try if the app works correctly with an [auth state listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#addAuthStateListener(com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener))? Something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth auth) {
            FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                sendUserToMainActivity();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

If that works, it seems that `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` is not yet set by the time your `onStart` runs.

Comment: Sir actually my last username stays stored already, I don't know how. I tried logout before uninstalling. Then when I install the app from play store and then on starting it sends me to MainActivity, as 'user' not returns null but the actual username last stored.